# I can't display extended values of my user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-profiles

On this case my problem arise displaying extended values of my user model in my index.html

here my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def url(self,filename):
    ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/%s/%s"%(self.user.username,filename)
    return ruta

class userProfile(models.Model):    

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

my index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Inicio - Bienvenidos {% endblock %}
{% block content %} 
<p>Dracoin, el portal que facilitará tu vida</p>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Bienvenido {{ user.username }}</p>
    {% if user.get_profile.photo %}
        <img src="/media/{{user.get_profile.photo}}" width="100px" height="100px"/>
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.get_profile.telefono %}
        <p>Numero Tel: {{user.get_profile.telefono}}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I don't have problem managing that information in my admin panel but i cant view that information in my index. I believe the mistake is in {% if user.get_profile.xxxx %} calling but I cant solve it.

apologizeme in advance if I overlook something.

Thanks!!

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_profile()` was deprecated in django 1.5, and removed in django 1.7.

Try `{{ user.userprofile.xxxx }}` instead.